# onclick modal button call a php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When click in modal button then a PHP function called and this PHP function retrieve data from DB and show in modal.

I am trying but confused. Any  Example

**modal button**

```
<?php
    foreach($pa as $pitem)
    {
        print'<div class="col span_1_of_4">
                  <div class="pcimga">
                      <div class="pcimg"><img src="Portfolio_Image/'.$pitem[6].'" class="pcimg" /></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pcsdes">'.$pitem[1].'</div>
                  <div class="pcctg"><span class="pcctgb">'.$pitem[5].'</span></div>
                  <div class="pclink">
                      <span class=" butnn"><a data-toggle="modal"  id="'.$pitem[0].'" href="#myModal">View</a></span>
                  </div>
              </div>';
    }
?>
```

here I want to show db result in modal depending on this `id="'.$pitem[0].'"` which carry on modal button.

**My modal code:**

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">'.$pitem[1].'====='.$pitem[0].'</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="col-md-6 column">
                        <div class="row clearfix">
                            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                                <img alt="140x140" src="'.$pitem[6].'"" class="img-responsive" />                           
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row clearfix">
                            <div class="col-md-12 column">
                                <div id="pad">                          
                                    <a href="'.$pitem[4].'" target="_blank"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg "> View</button></a>                           
                                </div>                          
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 column">
                        <p>'.$pitem[3].'"</p>                   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here I assume that db data come by this ( `$pitem[6]`) array using foreach loop from function.

I want to call a function like

```
$pai = $c -> Select_by_id($id);
```

Comment: make your question clear please, where is the function? Do you want to use ajax or normal request?

Answer (score 1):

You can make ajax call on button click to reach that php function.

```
    $('#btn-id').click(function(){
       $.ajax({
            url: 'url',
            data: { var1:value},                        
            type: 'post',
            success: function (data) {
            }

       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not call a PHP function that way, you must make the request via REQUEST or AsyncrAjax if you do not want to reload the page, with code like as @Ravi Mishra

Answer (score 0):

You can load modal content with following code;

```
$('[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".modal").modal("hide"); // Close all modals first
  var url = 'your_base_url?id=' + $(this).attr('id');
  $.get(url, function(data) {
      $(data).modal();
  });
});
```

Simply, I assigned this ajax content loading to all modals in page. I get id of clicked modal link, made an ajax request to your url with specific param

Comment: thanks. it works but i have seven item when i click one item modal button then it show and when i click another button then new item correctly show in modal but with previous.That means previous item modal running in back

Comment: You can close all modals first with `$(".modal").modal("hide")`. See my updated answer